# Computed Column that doesn't auto update

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a computed column that is automatically creating a confirmation number by adding the current max ID to some Prefix. It works, but not exactly how I need it to work.

This is the function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SetEPNum](@IdNum INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
return (select 'SomePrefix' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(MAX(IdNum) AS VARCHAR(255)), 5)
FROM dbo.someTable
/*WHERE IdNum = @IdNum*/)

END
```

If I add WHERE IdNum = @IdNum to the select in the function, that gives the illusion of working, but in reality it is picking the max IdNUM from the one row where IDNum = @IdNum rather than actually picking the current max IDNUM from all IDNums. If I remove the where statement, the computed function simply sets every field to the max Id every time it changes.

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[someTable](
[IdNum] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[First_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Last_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EPNum]  AS ([dbo].[SetEPNum]([IdNum]))
) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO

 SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
 GO
```

This is the computed column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.someTable
ADD EPNum AS dbo.SetEPnum(IdNum)
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? If not, is there an alternative solution?

Comment: I think you need max(idnum) per group using `group by`. show some sample data and how you want the computed column to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you try to get the max id of some table to appear next to each record at the time it was updated? 
Right now you get the same max id next to all records.

That is because the max id is one and only one. You have provided no context.

It seems to me this is the job of a trigger or even your update statement. Why employ computed columns? The computed column gets recomputed every time you display the data.

If you absolutely need to go this way, you should employ some other field (e.g. modification date) and get the max id from those records that were updated before the current. It all depends though on the business logic of your application and what you try to achieve.

Comment: Your method of answering wasn't really helpful. It came off more as screeching at me for why I am doing this and that, rather than suggesting a solution or a detailed alternative. However, it did lead me toward the solution I needed in a round about way, so I am marking your answer as the answer. I dropped the function and computed field entirely and created an update SPROC.

Comment: I had no bad intentions, so excuse me if it came out like this. My goal was to point out that your approach wouldn't achieve what you set out to do. I gave you only a hint rather than a detailed example, because the final decision depends on the rest of your application, of which I knew next to nothing. I'm glad you figured it out in the end.